# Website appearing different from chrome to firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, rendering

Im having some issues with how the content on a website im designing is appearing.

The content was originally designed and working normally in chrome but when I open the site in firefox or chrome on android i get the following issue.

[Screenshot in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7IeE.png)

[Screenshot in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeSWU.png)

The site is being rendered exactly the same through the inputs have a black background and the main div appears to have a shadow over it.

If anyone has had a similar issue that they have been able to solve Id greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Its hard to say without source. From the look of the two images I'd say there's a class (or more) active on the entire of the Firefox version.  There seems to be a red border on the information textarea in the Firefox version.  Was there an attempted submission and validation failed and somewhere along the line a class was applied?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Firefox adds automatically a red border for `:required` fields.

If you want to override this behavior you can do:

```
input:required {
    box-shadow: inherit;
}
```

I ended up doing

```
input:required {
    box-shadow: inherit;
}
input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #7AA6ff;
}
```

to have a normalized behavior cross-browser.